# air coming out of nose when playing

Tags: clarinet

I've been playing the clarinet for 1 year. I used to have a problem with air coming out of my nose when playing.  It went away for a bunch of months and is now coming back a little.  If anyone has any advice I would appriciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Practice breathing exercises and air control, you might be blowing too hard if air is also coming out your nose.

Comment: You can practice and train to close the way that the air searches to pass through your nose by pressing and forming in your mouth a strong **nnggkkhh**

Comment: Do you have a teacher? Hard to see what is happening here. Do you have the feeling that you are blowing very hard? It should not be a big physical effort.

Answer (score 2):

**You're not alone!**

I play the clarinet since I'm 7, and while being young, I was playing at least once or twice every week.
But during my studies, I was unable to play with my orchestra, and the more I could do was once avery 2 months.

After one year, while I was about 21, I started to have the same problem you describe.
At the beginning, it occurred at the end of rehearsals, when I was tired. I didn't pay attention.

But things became embarrassing when **it occurred during a concert, while I was playing a solo.**

At the end of my studies, I played again regularly, and the problem was there during the first rehearsals, **but progressively went away.**

So, I think this is a "muscle" that has to be trained to "close" correctly.

Also, try using **easy-to-play mouthpiece and reeds**, it can help, specially at the beginning.